# In what issue of Life magazine was "Misguided 'Guide'" first published?

Tags: textual-history, essays, r-k-narayan, the-guide, a-writers-nightmare

R K Narayan's *A Writer's Nightmare: Selected Essays 1958–1998* (New Delhi: Penguin, 1988) reprints "Misguided 'Guide'" on pp. 206–217. The essay recounts his experiences during the making of the [movie version](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12581060/) (1965) of his novel *The Guide* (1958). The copyright page states that this essay originally appeared in *Life* magazine, but provides no specific information about issue or year. Extensive research (i.e., cursory googling) yields several [essays](https://scroll.in/reel/911745/dev-anands-guide-the-back-story-of-the-english-version-is-far-more-interesting-than-the-movie), [blogs](https://alchetron.com/R-K-Narayan), etc. that mention this essay and its appearance in *Life*, but I have been unable to track down the bibliographic particulars. **In what volume and issue of *Life* did "Misguided 'Guide'" appear?**

Comment: A dead end for me, but maybe useful for someone else: Most articles/books that cite "Misguided Guide" say it's from 13/15 May 1967. I couldn't find that issue when I looked through _Life_ archives, though.

Comment: @CDR: *Life Magazine* was weekly; online, one can find people selling issues from May 12, 1967, May 19, 1967, and May 26, 1967. It seems very unlikely that there was a May 13/15, 1967 issue. These citations must all be copied from some erroneous source, which probably typoed the day, the month, or maybe even the year.

Comment: @PeterShor - sorry, I meant that some sources had May 13, and some had May 15; either way, as you said, neither seems to have existed.

Comment: @CDR: There was a May 13, 1966, *Life Magazine*. Maybe that's one place to start looking.

Comment: There used to be (is?) an Asia edition of the Magazine. Couple of these volumes are available on etsy and ebay. Books such as "The World of Malgudi" by A. Hariprasanna also quotes "Asia edition". So, I'm guessing that's where the piece was published.

Comment: @Padmanābha thank you for this info. If you convert this into an answer (including the full reference from Hariprasanna's or some other work that gives the issue date and specifies Asia edition) I will be delighted and will accept the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to say that "Misguided 'Guide'" **did not appear in the U.S.-based magazine called *Life*** that was published by Meredith Publishing and later by Time-Life, and that if this article was published, it was in either a different magazine called *Life* (possibly an Indian magazine) or some other magazine entirely.

The 1983 [Bibliography of Indian Writing in English: R. K. Narayan](https://archive.org/details/bibliographyofin0001hpon/page/60/mode/2up?q=%22misguided+guide%22) by H. Pontes cites "Misguided 'Guide'" from *Life* (May 13, 1967) pp. 49-57.

*Life* was a weekly magazine; there was no issue dated May 13, 1967. There was an issue dated May 13, 1966, and another May 12, 1967.

I have access to both the online archives and bound print copies.

- A search of the online archives finds no articles by an author named Narayan anywhere in *Life* between 1936 and 2000.
- The May 13, 1966, print issue has an article about Lynda Bird on pp. 51-56. I looked at every page of this issue and did not find anything by or about R.K. Narayan.
- The May 12, 1967, print issue has full-page ads and articles about the war in Viet Nam on pp 51-52 and 54-55. I looked at every page of this issue and did not find anything by or about R.K. Narayan.
- I also checked the Letters to the Editor and opinion columns and the table of contents for every issue of *Life* in May and June of 1966 and 1967 (the print issues are bound two months to a book), without finding anything remotely related to this movie or this man.
- I also searched Academic Search Complete and JSTOR, expanding the search to all periodicals indexed in these databases (not just *Life*), and found only reviews of Narayan's books.
- Just in case the original source for this information was confused about the magazine name, I also checked the bound print copies of the competing magazine called *Look* and found no references to R.K. Narayan in the May 17, 1966, and May 16, 1967, issues.

I know he wrote the article because he's reprinted it a few times, but I don't see where it's been published in a periodical.

Comment: When you say "English version," what do you mean? Narayan wrote the essay in English; it is not translated from another language. Do you mean the version published in England?

Comment: @verbose I don't know whether there might have been other editions. I'll clarify that I mean the magazine published in English in the U.S., since that's the only one I've been able to check. For all I know, maybe there was a magazine called _Life_ that was published in India.